# How to check two arrays and replace the data if the properties match

Tags: javascript, arrays, reduce

I have 2 array. As a result, I should get 1 array. If "groupPoint" matches, then take the data from the "data" array.

```
initialData = [
{groupPoint: '00:00', soldLeads: 0},
{groupPoint: '01:00', soldLeads: 0},
{groupPoint: '02:00', soldLeads: 0},
{groupPoint: '03:00', soldLeads: 0},
{groupPoint: '04:00', soldLeads: 0},
{groupPoint: '05:00', soldLeads: 0},
{groupPoint: '06:00', soldLeads: 0},
{groupPoint: '07:00', soldLeads: 0},
{groupPoint: '08:00', soldLeads: 0},
{groupPoint: '09:00', soldLeads: 0},
{groupPoint: '10:00', soldLeads: 0},
]

data = [
{groupPoint: '03:00', soldLeads: '4'},
{groupPoint: '04:00', soldLeads: '1'},
{groupPoint: '07:00', soldLeads: '1'}
]
```

**The result should be:**

```
result = [
{groupPoint: '00:00', soldLeads: 0},
{groupPoint: '01:00', soldLeads: 0},
{groupPoint: '02:00', soldLeads: 0},
{groupPoint: '03:00', soldLeads: '4'},
{groupPoint: '04:00', soldLeads: 0},
{groupPoint: '05:00', soldLeads: 0},
{groupPoint: '06:00', soldLeads: 0},
{groupPoint: '07:00', soldLeads: '4'},
{groupPoint: '08:00', soldLeads: '1'},
{groupPoint: '09:00', soldLeads: 0},
{groupPoint: '10:00', soldLeads: 0},
]
```

**But I have the result:**

```
initialData = [
{groupPoint: '00:00', soldLeads: 0},
{groupPoint: '01:00', soldLeads: 0},
{groupPoint: '02:00', soldLeads: 0},
{groupPoint: '03:00', soldLeads: '4'},
{groupPoint: '03:00', soldLeads: 0},
{groupPoint: '04:00', soldLeads: 0},
{groupPoint: '05:00', soldLeads: 0},
{groupPoint: '06:00', soldLeads: 0},
{groupPoint: '07:00', soldLeads: '4'},
{groupPoint: '07:00', soldLeads: 0},
{groupPoint: '08:00', soldLeads: '1'},
{groupPoint: '08:00', soldLeads: 0},
{groupPoint: '09:00', soldLeads: 0},
{groupPoint: '10:00', soldLeads: 0},
]
```

**My code (I would like to get this using reduce):**

```
 const result = initialData.reduce((acc, categoryItem, idx) => {
        return [
          ...acc,
          ...data
            .map((dataItem, index) => {
              if (categoryItem.groupPoint === dataItem.groupPoint) {
                return {
                  groupPoint: dataItem.groupPoint,
                  ...dataItem,
                };
              }
              if (index === data.length - 1 && !acc[idx]) {
                return { ...categoryItem };
              }
            })
            .filter(Boolean),
        ];
      }, []);
```

I see that the problem: !acc[idx] (it does not know that there is something in the "acc")

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Merge two array of objects based on matching properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66328888/merge-two-array-of-objects-based-on-matching-properties)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to create the new array and [`Array#find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) to search for a matching element from the other array.

```js
const initialData=[{groupPoint:"00:00",soldLeads:0},{groupPoint:"01:00",soldLeads:0},{groupPoint:"02:00",soldLeads:0},{groupPoint:"03:00",soldLeads:0},{groupPoint:"04:00",soldLeads:0},{groupPoint:"05:00",soldLeads:0},{groupPoint:"06:00",soldLeads:0},{groupPoint:"07:00",soldLeads:0},{groupPoint:"08:00",soldLeads:0},{groupPoint:"09:00",soldLeads:0},{groupPoint:"10:00",soldLeads:0},],data=[{groupPoint:"03:00",soldLeads:"4"},{groupPoint:"04:00",soldLeads:"1"},{groupPoint:"07:00",soldLeads:"1"}];
const res = initialData.map(x => data.find(y => y.groupPoint === x.groupPoint) ?? x);
// if a shallow copy is desired, use spread syntax:
// ({...data.find(y => y.groupPoint === x.groupPoint) ?? x})
console.log(res);
```

To avoid quadratic runtime, you can first create an object that maps each `groupPoint` from the second array to its corresponding object. Then apply `Array#map` after that, for a total time complexity of `O(n)`.

```js
const initialData=[{groupPoint:"00:00",soldLeads:0},{groupPoint:"01:00",soldLeads:0},{groupPoint:"02:00",soldLeads:0},{groupPoint:"03:00",soldLeads:0},{groupPoint:"04:00",soldLeads:0},{groupPoint:"05:00",soldLeads:0},{groupPoint:"06:00",soldLeads:0},{groupPoint:"07:00",soldLeads:0},{groupPoint:"08:00",soldLeads:0},{groupPoint:"09:00",soldLeads:0},{groupPoint:"10:00",soldLeads:0},],data=[{groupPoint:"03:00",soldLeads:"4"},{groupPoint:"04:00",soldLeads:"1"},{groupPoint:"07:00",soldLeads:"1"}];
const lookup = Object.fromEntries(data.map(o => [o.groupPoint, o]));
const res = initialData.map(o => lookup[o.groupPoint] ?? o);
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

**If you want to use `.reduce()`** you can use `.find()` to compare properties and push the new object to the accumulator.

```js
const result = initialData.reduce((acc, item) => {
  const foundItem = data.find((dataItem) => dataItem.groupPoint === item.groupPoint);
  acc.push({
    groupPoint: item.groupPoint,
    soldLeads: foundItem ? foundItem.soldLeads : 0
  });
  return acc;
}, []);
```

**I would however,** map over the array and use `.find` to compare the properties of the two objects.

```
const result = initialData.map((item) => {
  const foundItem = data.find((dataItem) => dataItem.groupPoint === item.groupPoint);
  return {
    groupPoint: item.groupPoint,
    soldLeads: foundItem ? foundItem.soldLeads : 0
  };
});
```